# How Can I make a Div Stretch According To Content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have a problem with auto width for a div, i don't want to give the div a static width i want it to set its width automatically to fit the content inside it.
i am trying to create a div with 3 lists, i made the lists (ul element) flex - column - wrap
i want the div stretch to fit lists if a list has more than column automatically.

This is my code snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.link-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 90%;
  gap: 30px;
}

.inner-list {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="inner-list">
      <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-list">
      <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark social </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark social </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-list">
      <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[i want to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfrAl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox has some known bugs, and one of them occurs when using `flex-flow: column wrap`. Some browsers don't properly size the container based on its content, which can result in unwanted overflow. To work around this, you can set the container to display: flex and flex-direction: row with a static height, like this:

> When using flex-flow: column wrap, some browsers do not properly size the container based on its content, and there is unwanted overflow.
>
> reference: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-14

### Workaround

To resolve the `flex: column` behavior, you can use `flex-flow: row wrap` instead (note the use of row instead of column). To fake the column behavior, you can update the container's writing mode (and reset it on the items), like this:

```
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
}
```

and resolve `flex: column` by using `flex-flow: row` wrap (note row instead of column) and fake the column behavior by updating the container's writing mode (and reseting it on the items).

```
.inner-list {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.inner-list li {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

### Example

Here's a full sample code and demo that should work for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
}

.link-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 90%;
  gap: 30px;
}

.inner-list {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.inner-list li {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="inner-list">
    <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-list">
    <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark social </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark social </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-list">
    <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `display: inline-table;` instead of flex and `width: 30%;`

```
.inner-list{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
}

.link-list{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 90%;
    gap: 30px;
    
    
}

.inner-list{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-table;
}

.inner-list ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="inner-list">
            <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-list">
            <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark social </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark social </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-list">
            <h6 class="inner-list-title">Title</h6>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't the OP say that they "*dont want to give the div a static width*" and "*want it to set its width automaticly*" [sic]?